# How to find and replace with AWK, but not when the preceding and following characters are alphanumeric?

Tags: bash, replace, awk

I need to surround all instances of `$word` with `<xml>` and `</xml>` in the variable `$line`, but not when alphanumeric characters appear immediately before or after. For e.g., given this line, if `$word` was set to "fish":

```
fish. The fish is a goldfish. Who likes fish?
```

This becomes:

```
<xml>fish</xml>. The <xml>fish</xml> is a goldfish. Who likes <xml>fish</xml>?
```

Here is what I tried so far with AWk, but it does not work:

```
echo "${line}" | awk '{
    gsub(/^|[^[:alnum:]]*($word)*$|[^[:alnum:]]*/, "<xml>&</xml>");
}1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sed should do the job:

```
> s='fish. The fish is a goldfish. Who likes fish?'
> sed -r 's#(^|[^[:alnum:]])(fish)([^[:alnum:]]|$)#\1<xml>\2</xml>\3#g' <<< "$s"
<xml>fish</xml>. The <xml>fish</xml> is a goldfish. Who likes <xml>fish</xml>?
```

Comment: @devnull: Thanks for the edit, I had pasted a different output from my testing.

Comment: It's __now__ that I'm able to figure the question.  I guess that you could simply the `sed` expression: `sed -r 's|\bfish\b|<xml>&</xml>|g'`

Comment: @devnull: I believe only difference between word boundary and non-alphanum is underscore. This will skip `fish_` and non-alphanum will convert this input.

Comment: This works, but when I replace "fish" with `$word` and set `$word="fish", why does it no longer add the tags to the words?

Comment: @Village: With shell variable use double quote like this: `sed -r "s#(^|[^[:alnum:]])($word)([^[:alnum:]]|$)#\1<xml>\2</xml>\3#g"`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the word boundary, can't seem to find an easy way to get that to work with gawk but here's a perl version instead:

```
echo 'fish. The fish is a goldfish. Who likes fish?' | perl -p -e 's/\b(fish)\b/<xml>\1<\/xml>/g'
<xml>fish</xml>. The <xml>fish</xml> is a goldfish. Who likes <xml>fish</xml>?
```

Comment: I believe only difference between word boundary and non-alphanum is underscore. This will skip `fish_` and `non-alphanum` will convert this input.

Comment: @anubhava: it's actually slightly more than that since it also takes the begin and end of string into consideration. If it's used before a word you'll get something like this: `(?(?=\w) (?<!\w) | (?<!\W) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "${line}" | sed s'@fish@<xml>fish</xml>@'g - My solution.
```